# How to delete HDF5 completely?

Tags: installation, python, uninstall

I want to run a Python script that uses the module netCDF4. Therefore I followed the instructions here: http://netcdf4-python.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/netCDF4-module.html

For what reason ever, it doesn't work with the HDF5-Version I installed. I installed the latest version (1.8.10) in my home-directory. But Python comes with this error:

```
$ import netCDF4
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/user/timo/<ipython-input-2-f731da2de255> in <module>()
----> 1 import netCDF4
/user/timo/netCDF4.pyx in init netCDF4 (netCDF4.c:46771)()
ImportError: netCDF4 module must be linked against HDF5 version 1.8.4-patch1 or higher, got 1.8.10
```

So I deleted the folders for the 1.8.10-Version (manually) from my home dir and installed the 1.8.4-patch1. (Maybe the '.10'-version is not compatible?)

But this doesn't solve the problem. The error when I run the Python script is still the same. That's why I thought there must be somewhere anything of the '.10'-version I did not delete, so I searched for 'hdf5':

```
4> sudo find / -name 'hdf5'
/user/timo/hdf5
/user/timo/Downloads/hdf5-1.8.4-patch1/windows/proj/hdf5
```

(in '/user/timo/hdf5' is the installed '1.8.4-patch1'-version)

I guess my Python script will run, after I have deleted the '1.8.10'-version completely. Can anyone help me out?

(I'm using 'Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS' and 'Python2.7')

Answer (score 0):

I am definitely also not an expert but looking at the netCDF4 page you have linked, you'll probably have to rebuild it after installing the older HDF5 version.

However I am wondering if you build netCDF4 with the flags that are listed under "Required", why the newest version should not work.

What does `export` say? Are your HDF5 variables set correct?

Answer (score 0):

I would remove both netCDF4 and HDF5 by running

```
apt-get remove --purge python-netcdf hdf5
```

This will also make go away related packages.

This might be more safe:

```
dpkg -r python-netcdf hdf5
apt-get autoremove
```

followed by reinstallation of netCDF4 and dependencies,
used most [from an article for Ubuntu 14 LTS](https://code.google.com/p/netcdf4-python/wiki/UbuntuInstall).

```
apt-get install git git-doc git-el git-email git-gui gitk gitweb git-arch git-bzr git-cvs git-mediawiki git-svn python python-dev python-pip libatlas-base-dev gcc gfortran g++ cython
```

this is good for avoiding later scipy python module errors [from www.scipy.org ]

```
apt-get install python-numpy python-scipy python-matplotlib ipython ipython-notebook python-pandas python-sympy python-nose
```

(re)install zlib library:

```
ftp.unidata.ucar.edu/pub/netcdf/netcdf-4/zlib-1.2.8.tar.gz
cd /home/user/Downloads
tar xvzf zlib-1.2.8.tar.gz
cd zlib-1.2.8
./configure 
make 
make install
```

(re)install curl:

```
apt-get install curl
```

(re)install HDF5:

```
ftp.unidata.ucar.edu/pub/netcdf/netcdf-4/hdf5-1.8.9.tar.gz
cd /home/user/Downloads 
tar xvzf hdf5-1.8.9.tar.gz
cd hdf5-1.8.9
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-shared --enable-hl
make -j 2
make install
```

(re)install netCDF4:

```
ftp.unidata.ucar.edu/pub/netcdf/netcdf-4.3.2.tar.gz
cd /home/user/Downloads
tar xvzf netcdf-4.3.2.tar.gz
cd netcdf-4.3.2

LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/lib CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/include ./configure --enable-netcdf-4 --enable-dap --enable-shared --prefix=/usr/local
make -j 2
make install
make check
```

and at last the netCDF4 module

```
pip install netcdf4
```

now the python "import netCDF4" should work